# User has admin rights but still unable to run command in cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator

I am an Administrator user and when I am trying to create a new user in cmd using `net user uname passwd /add` it gives me an error stating 'System error 5 has occured. Access is denied'

Why so?? I have administrator rights then why is it giving me the error?

Comment: Have you tried to open the cmd as administrator ?

Comment: You need to run the command prompt with the "run as administrator", and yes, you need to do this even as an Administrator because a process's permissions are not automatically elevated.

Comment: Thanks for the rply.. I don't want to run cmd as administrator but want to run with my own account which also has Administrator rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still required for CMD to run elevated (run as administrator) in order to make changes to the system.

If you didn't have a access popup (something like "program wants to make changes"...) then cmd window does not have proper access.

EDIT: This is part of the UAC implemented in Windows. You would need to disable it completely to have the effect described in question - and incidentally, it would work same as in XP.

Comment: I disabled the UAC completely and restarted the system.. And then I tried running the command again.. but still its giving errors..

Comment: @vjlxmi - You have not "disabled" UAC you have just configured it to automatically approve the action and not display the user prompt.

Comment: yeaah.. it worked.. Thank you.. :) You were right I was not "disabling" it..

Comment: I went to the following path Control panel>System & Security>Administrative Tools>Local Policy>Security Policy and disabled all the UAC options.. Instead of manually doing it step by step can it also be done via a command??

Comment: Locate this string in Windows Registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
and then find: EnableLUA. Setting it to 0 will disable UAC.
Should not be a problem converting it to cmd?