# Windows 10 administrator cannot run command prompt as admin

Tags: shell, cmd.exe, administrator

I am definitely administrator and am the only user account. I keep getting a ShellExecuteEx error when trying to run different EXE files (happens when running normally and when trying to run as admin), which I asked about [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1620010/shellexecuteex-code-31-error-any-time-i-try-to-launch-an-exe-how-to-find-proble).

I am trying to follow Step 2 [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-shellexecuteex-failed-error-on-windows/), which is to do `sfc /scannow`, but that requires running command prompt as admin.

When I try to run command prompt as admin, I get the same EXE run error: "A device attached to the system is not functioning."

So then I tried to follow the comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/922151/user-has-admin-rights-but-still-unable-to-run-command-in-cmd), which says to disable user account controls. However, when I open it up in control panel and drop it to the lowest level, and then click OK, my screen flashes very fast and nothing happens; it's like it doesn't register the change when I click it.

I think if I can figure out how to run command prompt as admin, all the other problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use these methods, see if they work:

1. Try looking through the running processes in the task manager. See if you get something suspicious.
2. Try the methods used [in this article by ComputerWeekly.](https://www.computerweekly.com/tip/Five-command-line-tools-to-detect-Windows-hacks)
3. If your computer's security has been compromised, then the attacker would have probably posted your passwords to a dark web forum or website. Try using [HaveIBeenPwned to find out.](https://haveibeenpwned.com)
4. Try to run CMD as a normal user, then type in: runas /user:username cmd. It will prompt you for the password, type it in, then it should run cmd as admin.(replace username with your username.)
5. Check which user accounts are created on the system using the net user command.
6. Finally, type in net user YourUsername to fetch your account's information.
7. During The Logon Screen, Hit Ctrl+Alt+Del to see if there are hidden accounts created on the computer.
   Hope This Helps :D